# Why does it seem like all the streamers are using colour-blind mode?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the graphics settings, my colour-blind mode is switched off. As a result, my health bar is green.

However, when I watch YouTube videos of streamers playing, almost all of their health bars are yellow. I mucked around with the graphics settings and discovered that I can recreate that colour by switching on colour blind mode.

My question is:

> Is there a reason for making the HP bar yellow instead of leaving it as green by default?

Comment: Easier to notice? Easier for colour blind folk? Personal preference? We are not the streamers - it's unlikely that you will get a definitive answer to this. (But people have surprised me before.)

Comment: I can completely understand that it'd be easier for colour blind people. But since almost every single streamer has it on, it leads me to think that there's another reason for it (unless they're ALL colour blind!). Perhaps somebody who plays at a more competitive level can shed some light on this? The streamers generally are quite high up so there must be some sort of advantage for it.

Comment: Im not a streamer, but I put it on because its hard to keep track of myself in chaotic fights, and the yellow stands out better

Comment: I would presume it is because close to 1 in 10 poeple are colour-blind, so having your videos compatible with them increases your potential audience significantly.

Comment: I personally think both arguments (visibility and audience) are important here. Plus the fact that you usually look at stream from a longer distance of your screen than when you're playing, more contrasted colors are easier to follow.

Answer (score 5):

To reiterate what has been said in the comments, but in an answer, at least two possible reasons:

### 1. Colorblind viewers

Some viewers will most likely be colorblind, especially with popular streamers who consistantly get thousands of viewers. Having the setting enabled makes the stream 'compatible' with their sight so that they can watch the stream.

### 2. Contrast

Colorblind mode adds some contrast to the colors, making things more distinguishable, which is very useful, especially in teamfights etc. Also, this is nicer for the viewers as it will make the stream easier to watch from a distance or in a smaller area of their screen, as they may be lounging back in their chair or not have the stream fullscreen.

Comment: Good use of a cliffhanger. So curious what the third possible reason is :)

Comment: For an example, my SO noted specifically non-colourblind has green markers which can be hard to see on green grass.  Colourblind mode makes them blue.

Comment: @Flater cliffhanger?

Comment: @Quelklef: It's like the informant who gets killed right after he says "I know who did it" but before he utters the name. You said 3 options but gave only 2 :)

Comment: "To reiterate what has been said in the comments, but in an answer, at least two possible reasons:" ... ??? I said at least, since there may be more than I'm listing.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience (a few years, platinum ELO), I find it easier to pick out the yellow health bars over the green.  The green blends in with the grass background, making it harder to tell at a glance what percentage I'm at, colourblind mode fixes that.

I think there is some truth to the theory about colourblind viewers for streamers, but from a playing perspective, it's generally easier to spot your health bar out of a crowd with colourblind mode on.

For most players (non-streamers specifically) I think it's just a personal preference.